# Vectorize a Convex Hull and Interpolation loop on a specific axis of an ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, convex-hull

I'm struggling to find an efficient way to implement this interpolated convex hull data treatment.

I have a 2D ndarray, call it `arr`, with shape (2000000,19), containing floats.
I have a 1D ndarray, call it `w`, with shape (19,), also containing floats.

What I achieved (and works perfectly except that it's excruciatingly slow) is the following:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

# Sample data
arr = np.array([[49.38639913, 49.76769437, 49.66370476, 49.49905455, 49.15242251,
        48.0518658 , 45.998071  , 45.31347273, 45.29614113, 45.25281212,
        45.0448329 , 44.61154286, 43.72763117, 42.38443203, 41.17121991,
        40.48662165, 40.35663463, 39.88001558, 39.55938095],
       [47.97387359, 47.86121818, 47.69656797, 47.18528571, 46.70000087,
        45.39146494, 43.50232035, 43.18168571, 43.82295498, 43.62364156,
        43.31167273, 42.88704848, 42.37576623, 41.0585645 , 40.37396623,
        39.09142771, 38.79679048, 38.51948485, 38.52815065]])
w = np.array([2.1017, 2.1197, 2.1374, 2.1548, 2.172 , 2.1893, 2.2068, 2.2254,
       2.2417, 2.2592, 2.2756, 2.2928, 2.3097, 2.326 , 2.3421, 2.3588,
       2.3745, 2.3903, 2.4064])
```

```py
def upper_andrews_hull(points: np.ndarray):
    """
    Computes the upper half of the convex hull of a set of 2D points.
    :param points: an iterable sequence of (x, y) pairs representing the points.
    """
    # 2D cross product of OA and OB vectors, i.e. z-component of their 3D cross product.
    # Returns a positive value, if OAB makes a counter-clockwise turn,
    # negative for clockwise turn, and zero if the points are collinear.
    def cross(o, a, b):
        return (a[0] - o[0]) * (b[1] - o[1]) - (a[1] - o[1]) * (b[0] - o[0])

    # Reverse the points so that we can pop from the end
    points = np.flip(points, axis=0)
    # Build upper hull
    upper = []
    for p in points:
        while len(upper) >= 2 and cross(upper[-2], upper[-1], p) <= 0:
            upper.pop()
        upper.append(p)
    # Reverse the upper hull
    upper = np.flip(np.array(upper), axis=0)

    return upper
```

```py
result = np.empty(arr.shape)
for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
    # Create points, using w as x values, and arr as y values
    points = np.stack((w, arr[i,:]), axis=1)
    # Calculate the convex hull around the points
    hull = upper_andrews_hull(points)
    # Interpolate the hull
    interp_function = interp1d(*hull.T)
    # Store interpolation's result to have the same x references as original points
    result[i,:] = interp_function(w)
```

I'm pretty sure that there's a way to forego the loop and only use vectorial calculations, but I can't find it (plus, there's the issue that `hull` doesn't always have the same number of points, so all of the hulls would not be storable in an ndarray.

My expected behaviour would be something like `result = interpolated_hull(arr, w, axis=0)`, to apply the operations on the entire `arr` array without a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using `numba` in your code? This gives me a speed improvement on my machine by a factor of:

- `loop_hulls_numba`: ~70 (single core) or 70s to 0.973s
- `loop_hulls_numba_parallel`: ~350 (multiple cores) or 70s to 0.223s (depends strongly on the number of CPUs)

based on a 2'000'000 by 16 array!

Speed tests are performed with `timeit`, i.e. `%timeit -n 3 -r 3 loop_hulls_numba(w, arr_n)`. `numba` needs some extra time for the first compilation, which I excluded in the speed test.

## Generate a bigger array for testing

```py
n = int(2e6)
arr_n = np.resize(arr, (n, 19))
```

## The numba solution

```py
@jit(nopython=True)
def cross_numba(o, a, b):
    return (a[0] - o[0]) * (b[1] - o[1]) - (a[1] - o[1]) * (b[0] - o[0])

@jit(nopython=True)
def upper_andrews_hull_numba(x: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray):
    """
    Computes the upper half of the convex hull of a set of 2D points.
    :param points: an iterable sequence of (x, y) pairs representing the points.
    """
    # 2D cross product of OA and OB vectors, i.e. z-component of their 3D cross product.
    # Returns a positive value, if OAB makes a counter-clockwise turn,
    # negative for clockwise turn, and zero if the points are collinear.
    
    # Build upper hull
    upper = [(x[-1], y[-1]), 
             (x[-2], y[-2])]
    # Reverse the points so that we can pop from the end
    for p in zip(x[-3::-1], y[-3::-1]):
        while len(upper) >= 2 and cross_numba(upper[-2], upper[-1], p) <= 0:
            upper.pop()
        upper.append(p)

    # Reverse the upper hull
    return upper[::-1]

@jit(nopython=True)
def loop_hulls_numba(w, arr):
    result = np.zeros(arr.shape)
    for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
        # Calculate the convex hull around the points
        hull = np.array(upper_andrews_hull_numba(w, arr[i,:]))
        # # Interpolate the hull
        x, y = hull.T
        result[i,:] = np.interp(w, x, y)
    return result
```

## Get the maximum out of your CPU by parallelization

```py
@jit(nopython=True, parallel=True)
def loop_hulls_numba_parallel(w, arr):
    result = np.zeros(arr.shape)
    for i in prange(arr.shape[0]):
        # Calculate the convex hull around the points
        hull = np.array(upper_andrews_hull_numba(w, arr[i,:]))
        # # Interpolate the hull
        x, y = hull.T
        result[i] = np.interp(w, x, y)
    return result
```

Comment: Thanks, that does improve execution time. I don't get the same improvement factor as you, though, only about 3 fold instead of 50 as you mention.

Comment: Got your question wrong. You want to calculate 2e6 hulls with 19 points each instead of 19 hulls with 1e6 points. Use the updated answer, this should nearly give you the 50 factor. It's 38 on my machine by fully deploying Numba in the code. And `scipy.interp` is slower as `np.interp` in your case, because you use the interpolation only once + `numba` understand just `numpy` not `scipy`.

Comment: Now that's what I call some improvement! Thank you very much, it helps a lot. And your explanations are very welcome

Comment: Added a version with Numba parallelization in the answer. Gives for me another speed factor of 5 -> ~350 in total! Next step would be to move this to an GPU, but this requires a bit more work and will not run everywhere out of the box.

Comment: That sounds incredible! I tried it, but it keeps making my python session crash with no error.

Comment: I'm using: `import numba`
`numba.__version__` -> 0.58.1 &
`np.__version__`  -> 1.26.3

Comment: `numba.__version__` -> 0.58.0 & `np.__version__` -> 1.25.2. Do you think that might be it?

Comment: Stange. Don't think so. But give it a try with a new env.

Comment: The Numpy  implementation of Numba does not check bounds as opposed to Numpy. If this happens, then the results is undefined (often a crash but possibly also a data corruption). You can add `boundscheck=True` so to track some bad accesses. This does not track all errors though (e.g. no race condition checks which should not happen here anyway). Note that old versions of Numba tends to be unfortunately bogus with complex parallel codes.

Comment: I haven't had the chance to try with the more recent versions kho suggested. But using `boundscheck=True` didn't change anything, python is still crashing.